# Python set() and list() functions together

Tags: python, list, set

Looking through some python code I encountered this line:

```
x = list(set(range(height)) - set(array))
```

where array is just an int array. It's guaranteed that array's len is less than height.
Could someone please explain me how does it work?
Thanks!

Comment: Which part precisely do you not understand at the moment? Have you tried splitting it into multiple steps and adding `print`s to explore what's happening?

Comment: Specifically, do you know what `set` and `list` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take sample values and see what's happening here

```
height = 5   # height has to be an integer for range()
array = [1,1,2,3]
x = list(set(range(height)) - set(array))
print(x)    # [0,4]
```

Let's break it down into smaller pieces of code

```
height = 5
array = [1,1,2,3]
a = range(height)       # Generates a list [0,1,2,3,4]
a_set = set(a)          # Converts a into a set (0,1,2,3,4)
b_set = set(array)      # Converts array into a set (1,2,3)
x_set = a_set - b_set   # Does set operation A-B, ie, removes elements of B from A. (0,4)
x = list(x_set)         # Converts it into a list [0,4]
print(x)    # [0,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I an guessing height is an int.

What your script does is that it returns a list of all distinct values from 0 to 'height' , height not included, that do not appear in your array.

Answer (score 0):

The range of a number returns 0 up to that number.

`set()` of a collection removes all duplicate elements

You can subtract two sets, which is called the difference, returning all elements that are not shared between them.

The result is casted back to a list and assigned to the variable